# Matplotlib Subplot issues

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I am struggling with plotting different columns of data from a data frame into 3 different subplots.

All the data is falling into the third subplot, and no data is falling into the second subplot, etc.

```
# Set up the axes with gridspec
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
grid = plt.GridSpec(2, 4, wspace=1.0, hspace=0.2)

fig_ax1 = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, :2])
fig_ax1.set_title('Graph 1')
fig_ax1 = df['VARIABLE A'].hist(bins=30, color='purple')


fig_ax2 = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, 2:])
fig_ax2.set_title('Graph 2')
fig_ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x='VARIABLE B',y='VARIABLE A', c='Red')

fig_ax3 = fig.add_subplot(grid[1, 0:])
fig_ax3.set_title('Graph 3')
fig_ax3 = df['VARIABLE B'].hist(bins=30, orientation='horizontal')
```

I figured it is the final statement for each graph where I am declaring the data to plot. How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your `ax` as a parameter to the pandas plot commands. By default, pandas creates the plot using the "current ax". This `ax` is returned to make it easier to make adjustments. If you already have created your own `ax` beforehand, you need to pass it as the `ax=` parameter.

The pandas documentation explains this in the [visualization chapter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/visualization.html#using-layout-and-targeting-multiple-axes), under "targeting multiple axes".

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'VARIABLE A': np.random.randn(100), 'VARIABLE B': np.random.randn(100)})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
grid = plt.GridSpec(2, 4, wspace=1.0, hspace=0.2)

fig_ax1 = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, :2])
fig_ax1.set_title('Graph 1')
df['VARIABLE A'].hist(bins=30, color='purple', ax=fig_ax1)

fig_ax2 = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, 2:])
fig_ax2.set_title('Graph 2')
df.plot.scatter(x='VARIABLE B', y='VARIABLE A', c='Red', ax=fig_ax2)

fig_ax3 = fig.add_subplot(grid[1, 0:])
fig_ax3.set_title('Graph 3')
df['VARIABLE B'].hist(bins=30, orientation='horizontal', ax=fig_ax3)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks alot JohanC! That did it - apologises I couldn't get my head around the ax= part before (while I was googling in vain for the answer) but this makes it very clear now!

Much appreciated!